# What java applet does Facebook use to upload images?

Tags: java, image, facebook, upload, applet

I am trying to write a Java image uploader, but I want to "Browse Files" with preview. Best way for me (and my boss) is .. to open default (windows|*) "Browse Files" window, but I can't.

I have a few solutions, first is the JFileChooser (which is very ugly). 
Can you give me some ideas, to realize this thing?

PP As here, or Facebook image upload?

Comment: The Facebook image upload selector isn't a Java applet, it's an HTML `<input type="file">` element.  The browse feature is implemented in the browser, typically using the system's standard file-selection dialog.

Comment: At first I was going to vote to close this as NARQ for being too broad, but it's an architecture question at heart, so I voted to move to Programmers SE.

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of the normal `<input type="file">`. Facebook does not use a Java applet. You can also try using jQuery(has some good UI),thats if you are interested in getting involved with Javascript.